# Is it possible to track the total time the script is running?

Tags: imacros

Is there any method to track the total time the script is running.
I tried to make it with new Date();

like this

```
var StartTime = new Date();
var StartTimeH = StartTime.getHours();
var StartTimeM = StartTime.getMinutes();
var EndTime, EndTimeH, EndTimeM;
```

But it's not showing time correctly, is there any other method or maybe any ideas how can i make changes to this code;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood this issue, you can try to adjust the following code:

```
var StartTime = new Date();

// your script here
iimPlayCode("WAIT SECONDS=123");

var EndTime = new Date();

var timeM = Math.floor((EndTime - StartTime) / (60 * 1000));
var timeH = Math.floor(timeM / 60);
var timeM = timeM - 60 * timeH;
alert("Hours: " + timeH + " Minutes: " + timeM);
```